# How to change R Script author name in metadata

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

My R script headers, automatically fill my name.

Everytime open a new R script, it autofill name and date, but didn't show on R script.

Only when I use "knitr document" in Rstudio, compiling R script to HTML,  Find out under the title, there are my name and date. So anyone help me to delete default name in R script

```
#' ---
```

`#' title: "Crop Analysis Q3 2013"`

`#' author: "John Smith"`

`#' date: "May 3rd, 2014"`

```
#' ---
```

This way can change, but I try to figure out how to change in some file.

Even after I changed Mac user name, system User name,  still show the old name.

Rstudio: 1.2.5033; R version 3.6.3； MacOS;

Comment: It is common to add information on your operating system, the names and version numbers of the software you are using. Then a very specific but short question explaining what you have done and its results.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***spin*** function from ***knitr*** library. Make sure you are on the right directory where you would like to make the HTML file.

> knitr::spin("example.R")

Above command will make two file in our working directory.

1. HTML file
2. RMD File